# Perl libXML find node by attribute value

Tags: perl, libxml2

I have very large XML document that I am iterating through.  The XML's use mostly attributes rather than node values.  I may need to find numerous nodes in the file to piece together one grouping of information.  They are tied together via different ref tag values.  Currently each time I need to locate one of the nodes to extract data from I am looping through the entire XML and doing a match on the attribute to find the correct node.  Is there a more efficient way to just select a node of a given attribute value instead of constantly looping and compare?  My current code is so slow it is almost useless.

Currently I am doing something like this numerous times in the same file for numerous different nodes and attribute combinations.

```
my $searchID = "1234";
foreach my $nodes ($xc->findnodes('/plm:PLMXML/plm:ExternalFile')) {
    my $ID      = $nodes->findvalue('@id');
    my $File    = $nodes->findvalue('@locationRef');
    if ( $searchID eq $ID ) {
        print "The File Name = $File\n";
    }
}
```

In the above example I am looping and using an "if" to compare for an ID match.  I was hoping I could do something like this below to just match the node by attribute instead... and would it be any more efficient then looping?

```
my $searchID = "1234";
$nodes = ($xc->findnodes('/plm:PLMXML/plm:ExternalFile[@id=$searchID]'));
my $File    = $nodes->findvalue('@locationRef');
print "The File Name = $File\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Do one pass to extract the information you need into a more convenient format or to build an index.

```
my %nodes_by_id;
for my $node ($xc->findnodes('//*[@id]')) {
    $nodes_by_id{ $node->getAttribute('id') } = $node;
}
```

Then your loops become

```
my $node = $nodes_by_id{'1234'};
```

(And stop using `findvalue` instead of `getAttribute`.)

Comment: I'm surprised that `//.[@id]` works, as `.` represents the current context, and isn't really meaningful except as the first step in a path. `//*[@id]` is far more common

Comment: @Borodin, It's just a like in a file system. `/foo/bar/././baz` is the same thing as `/foo/bar/baz`. However, `*` matches only element nodes whereas `.` matches any node, so `*` is what I should have used. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ikegami.  This does simplify the code quite a bit and makes lookup of nodes much faster...once the hash table is built.  For what I would say is a small to medium size XML for me, the initial building of the hash takes about 5 minutes.  Not sure if there is a way to optimize even further to go faster or not?  Probably not.  Also, I switched over to getAttribute now.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to do some study on XPath expressions.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
my $search_id = "1234";
my $query = "/plm:PLMXML/plm:ExternalFile/[\@id = '$search_id']";
foreach my $node ($xc->findnodes($query)) {
    # ...
}
```

In the XPath expression you can also combine multiple attribute checks, e.g.:

```
[@id = '$search_id' and contains(@pathname, '.pdf')]
```

One [XPath Tutorial](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html) of [many](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=XPath+tutorial)

**Edit**: Another useful resource is the [XPath expressions page](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/xpath.html) in "Perl XML::LibXML by Example". The "TRY IT!" buttons on that page link to an "XPath Sandbox" page where you can try the example and edit it.  The sandbox also has a "+" button which allows you to work with your own XML document, including one with namespaces (the default example file doesn't have namespaces).

Answer (score 2):

If you will be doing this for lots of IDs, then ikegami's answer is worth reading.

> I was hoping I could do something like this below to just match the node by attribute instead
>
> ...
>
> ```
> $nodes = ($xc->findnodes('/plm:PLMXML/plm:ExternalFile[@id=$searchID]'));
> ```

Sort of.

For a given ID, yes, you can do

```
$nodes = $xc->findnodes("/plm:PLMXML/plm:ExternalFile[\@id=$searchID]");
```

... provided that `$searchID` is known to be numeric. Notice the double quotes in perl means the variables interpolate, so you should escape the `@id` because that is part of the literal string, not a perl array, whereas you want the value of `$searchID` to become part of the xpath string, so it is not escaped.

Note also that in this case you are asking for it in scalar context will have a [XML::LibXML::Nodelist](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::NodeList) object, not the actual node, nor an arrayref; for the latter you will need to use square brackets instead of round ones as I have done in the next example.

Alternatively, if your search id may not be numeric but you know for sure that it is safe to be put in an XPath string (e.g. doesn't have any quotes), you can do the following:

```
$nodes = [ $xc->findnodes('/plm:PLMXML/plm:ExternalFile[@id="' . $searchID . '"]') ];
print $nodes->[0]->getAttribute('locationRef'); # if you're 100% sure it exists
```

Notice here that the resulting string will enclose the value in quotation marks.

Finally, it is possible to skip straight to:

```
print $xc->findvalue('/plm:PLMXML/plm:ExternalFile[@id="' . $searchID . '"]/@locationRef');
```

... providing you know that there is only one node with that id.

Comment: Re "If you will be doing this for lots of IDs", The OP specifically said he had many loops. At best, you created a slight improvement to each loop, but my approach eliminates all but one loop.

Comment: `my @nodes = $xc->findnodes(...);` would make more sense. `my ($node) = $xc->findnodes(...);` would make even more sense.

Comment: My ids's are not numeric.  They all have an id prefix.  Like this: <ExternalFile id="id104" accessRefs="#id91" locationRef="0000145.xls" format="xls">

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DTD for your document that declares the `id` attribute as DTD `ID`, and you make sure the DTD is read when parsing the document, you can access the elements with a certain id efficiently via [`$doc->getElementById($id)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Document#getElementById).